# Memory leak of AudioTrack

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, audiotrack

I encountered a severe problem of memory leak when AudioTrack and MediaSync are used together. It seems to me, the problem is that AudioTrack doesn't release some native resources. As a result, the app can be run only several times, after that, AudioTrack can't be created since there are no available tracks any more.

Below is a short example which causes the memory leak. The full project may be downloaded [here](https://github.com/AntonKosov/AudioTrackMemoryLeak) on GitHub. APK file may be downloaded [here](https://github.com/AntonKosov/AudioTrackMemoryLeak/releases/download/1.0/AudioTrackMemoryLeak.apk).

```
final MediaSync mediaSync = new MediaSync();
mediaSync.setSurface(mSurface);
final Surface inputSurface = mediaSync.createInputSurface(); // There is no the memory leak if I don't create this input surface.

final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack.Builder()
        .setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MOVIE)
                .build())
        .setAudioFormat(new AudioFormat.Builder()
                .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
                .setSampleRate(48000)
                .setChannelMask(12)
                .build())
        .build();
mediaSync.setAudioTrack(audioTrack); // There is no the memory leak if I don't set AudioTrack.

mediaSync.release();
inputSurface.release();
audioTrack.release();
```

I reproduce the issue in the following way:

1. Run the app.
2. Press the Home button, run again. Repeat it approximately 14 times, after that get the error.

Logcat:

```
2019-03-15 09:19:57.313 239-15387/? E/AudioFlinger: no more track names available
2019-03-15 09:19:57.313 239-15387/? E/AudioFlinger: createTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2019-03-15 09:19:57.313 3413-3413/com.audiotrackmemoryleak E/AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
2019-03-15 09:19:57.313 3413-3413/com.audiotrackmemoryleak E/AudioTrack-JNI: Error -12 initializing AudioTrack
2019-03-15 09:19:57.313 3413-3413/com.audiotrackmemoryleak E/android.media.AudioTrack: Error code -20 when initializing AudioTrack.
2019-03-15 09:19:57.315 3413-3413/com.audiotrackmemoryleak D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-03-15 09:19:57.316 3413-3413/com.audiotrackmemoryleak E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.audiotrackmemoryleak, PID: 3413
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot create AudioTrack
        at android.media.AudioTrack$Builder.build(AudioTrack.java:776)
        at com.audiotrackmemoryleak.MainActivity.createMediaSync(MainActivity.java:68)
        at com.audiotrackmemoryleak.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:18)
        at com.audiotrackmemoryleak.MainActivity$1.surfaceCreated(MainActivity.java:32)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:618)
        at ...
```

The command `adb shell dumpsys media.audio_flinger` demonstrates the problem:

```
...
Clients:             
  pid: 3413          
Notification Clients:
  pid: 239           
  pid: 841           
  pid: 3413          
  pid: 28651         
Global session refs: 
  session   pid count
     3193  3413     1
     3201  3413     1
     3209  3413     1
     3217  3413     1
     3225  3413     1
     3233  3413     1
     3241  3413     1
     3249  3413     1
     3257  3413     1
     3265  3413     1
     3273  3413     1
     3281  3413     1
     3289  3413     1
     3297  3413     1
...
          14 Tracks of which 0 are active
    Name Active Client Type      Fmt Chn mask Session fCount S F SRate  L dB  R dB    Server Main buf  Aux Buf Flags UndFrmCnt
       7     no   3413    3 00000001 00000003    3249   1924 I 0 48000     0     0  00000000 0xa77fe000 0x0 0x000         0
       5     no   3413    3 00000001 00000003    3233   1924 I 0 48000     0     0  00000000 0xa77fe000 0x0 0x000         0
      12     no   3413    3 00000001 00000003    3289   1924 I 0 48000     0     0  00000000 0xa77fe000 0x0 0x000         0
       3     no   3413    3 00000001 00000003    3217   1924 I 0 48000     0     0  00000000 0xa77fe000 0x0 0x000         0
       8     no   3413    3 00000001 00000003    3257   1924 I 0 48000     0     0  00000000 0xa77fe000 0x0 0x000         0
       9     no   3413    3 00000001 00000003    3265   1924 I 0 48000     0     0  00000000 0xa77fe000 0x0 0x000         0
       4     no   3413    3 00000001 00000003    3225   1924 I 0 48000     0     0  00000000 0xa77fe000 0x0 0x000         0
       1     no   3413    3 00000001 00000003    3201   1924 I 0 48000     0     0  00000000 0xa77fe000 0x0 0x000         0
      11     no   3413    3 00000001 00000003    3281   1924 I 0 48000     0     0  00000000 0xa77fe000 0x0 0x000         0
       0     no   3413    3 00000001 00000003    3193   1924 I 0 48000     0     0  00000000 0xa77fe000 0x0 0x000         0
       6     no   3413    3 00000001 00000003    3241   1924 I 0 48000     0     0  00000000 0xa77fe000 0x0 0x000         0
      13     no   3413    3 00000001 00000003    3297   1924 I 0 48000     0     0  00000000 0xa77fe000 0x0 0x000         0
       2     no   3413    3 00000001 00000003    3209   1924 I 0 48000     0     0  00000000 0xa77fe000 0x0 0x000         0
      10     no   3413    3 00000001 00000003    3273   1924 I 0 48000     0     0  00000000 0xa77fe000 0x0 0x000         0
  0 Effect Chains
...
```

I wonder if there's anyone here who can explain what's going on? How should I release AudioTrack properly?

Comment: not sure but try to release it after some delay. just try it.

Comment: I have already tried to do that; it doesn't work. Moreover, in my real project, the objects were released after a few minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it's an SDK bug or not but it's related to `AudioAttributes.FLAG_DEEP_BUFFER`. When you construct `AudioTrack` through the Builder this flag is set by default. See your case [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/AudioTrack.java#941): the check of `shouldEnablePowerSaving()` returns true and the switch case results in `PERFORMANCE_MODE_POWER_SAVING` with `FLAG_DEEP_BUFFER` enabled.

To fix this you should disable this flag by for example adding `.setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_LOW_LATENCY)` call to your `AudioAttributes`, but it requires min SDK 24. Otherwise you can abandon the use of `AudioTrack.Builder` altogether and construct the track like this:

```
    int audioSampleRate = 48000;
    int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO;
    int bufSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(audioSampleRate, channelConfig, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audioSampleRate,
            channelConfig, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

Or you can check [the code of `shouldEnablePowerSaving()` check](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/AudioTrack.java#1012) and make it not pass in any other way.

**UPDATE**:
So the above solution just moved the leak to another audio thread. I investigated further and noticed that `surfaceCreated()` hands the same `Surface` object on my android 8 device. And indeed, [this is the correct behaviour since android 7](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/SurfaceView.java#644). I assume it somehow breaks the mediaSync surface logic: if you remove the call to `mediaSync.createInputSurface()` and add `mediaSync.setSurface(null)` call before releasing it, the leak will be gone.

I don't know how to workaround this issue since the `Surface` being reused by the system and there's no way to know when it will be actually destroyed. I suggest switching to `TextureView`, it has similar but clearer API and doesn't destroy the surface on activity pause. You will need to remove the `createMediaSync()` call from `onResume()` and use it like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final TextureView textureView = findViewById(R.id.texture_view);

textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        mSurface = new Surface(surface);
        createMediaSync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        //release resources here
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    }
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, both solutions don't fix the memory leak.

Comment: I see, the leak just moved to another audio thread. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it out.

Comment: In case of interest, I made a decision not to use `MediaSync` at all. From my point of view, it's a very glitchy class. For example, `TextureView` stops drawing frames when `MediaSync` is used but works perfectly if I use `MediaCodec` directly.